SetSubComponent causing EReadError to raise in VCL
Following my last question, I have fallen into another problem:
I'm writing a small component to wrap two TscGPGlyphButton into TscPanel (both custom components from AlmediaDev, inheriting from TCustomControl and TComponent). All three elements appear in design time the exact way they should, but in runtime only the panel renders. I've read from other sources that it could be due:

DFM Corruption, but I created another form from the beginning and it had the same problem.
No parenting - if I remove parenting it also won't show on design time, but my problem seems to happen only in runtime.
Not set as SubComponent, which I think is the case only because once I add SetSubComponent (right after the instance creation as the docs tells to), the code goes from not showing to displaying:


Exception EReadError in module IUD.exe at 000BEADC.
Error reading ImprovedFluentTopBar1.CloseButton.Left:
Property CloseButton.Left does not exist.

Which is obviously not true: the property exists in its ancestors and is visible in the Object Inspector. For this case I have already inferred that it seems to happen during Form components creation, so my guess is that it's trying to access the .Left property before it even exists, but I don't know why. Also this theory was reinforced by the fact that the error becomes:

Exception EReadError in module IUD.exe at 000BEADC.
Error reading ImprovedFluentTopBar1.MinimizeButton.Left:
Property MinimizeButton.Left does not exist.

...if I change the order the properties are declared in the component class.
TL;DR: My first state was: Panel renders, buttons don't render. Added SetSubComponent to ComponentSetup (and afterwards moved it directly into the constructor as the code shows) and now it raises EReadError. I don't know what is happening.
The full code for the component:
interface

uses
 Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, scControls, scGPControls, scStyledForm, Constants.UI;

type
  TImprovedFluentTopBar = class(TscPanel)
  private
    FCloseButton: TscGPGlyphButton;
    FMinimizeButton: TscGPGlyphButton;
    procedure SetupComponent;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;

  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

  published
    property CloseButton: TscGPGlyphButton read FCloseButton;
    property MinimizeButton: TscGPGlyphButton read FMinimizeButton;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Improved UI Design', [TImprovedFluentTopBar]);
end;

{ TImprovedFluentPanel }

constructor TImprovedFluentTopBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  SetupComponent;

  if (AOwner <> nil) and (csDesigning in AOwner.ComponentState) then     // Pesquisar sobre isso aqui
  begin
    if not (AOwner is TForm) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Owner must be a TForm.');
    end;

    var Found: Boolean := False;
    for var I:Integer := 0 to TForm(AOwner).ComponentCount - 1 do   // Cast de AOwner para TForm. Acessa a componentCount do TForm.
    begin
      if TForm(AOwner).Components[I] is TImprovedFluentTopBar then
      begin
        {$IFNDEF DEBUG}
        raise Exception.Create('TImprovedFluentTopBar is already on the form.');
        {$ENDIF}
      end
      else if TForm(AOwner).Components[I] is TscStyledForm then
      begin
        Found := True;
      end;
    end;

    if not Found then
    begin
      {$IFNDEF DEBUG}
      //raise Exception.Create('TscStyledForm not found in current TForm');  // TO-DO Remove || fix: Raises exception everytime it loads the form designer (prob loaded b4 TscStyledForm?)
      {$ENDIF}
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TImprovedFluentTopBar.Resize;
begin
  inherited;

end;

procedure TImprovedFluentTopBar.SetupComponent;
begin
  FMinimizeButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FMinimizeButton.SetSubComponent(True);

  FCloseButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FCloseButton.SetSubComponent(True);

  Self.Caption := '';
  Self.DragForm := True;
  Self.Align := alTop;
  Self.Height := 28;

  FMinimizeButton.Name := 'MinButton';
  FCloseButton.Name := 'ClsButton';

  FMinimizeButton.Parent := Self;
  FMinimizeButton.Align := alRight;
  FMinimizeButton.Left := 10;

  FCloseButton.Parent := Self;
  FCloseButton.Align := alRight;
  FCloseButton.Left := 10;
  FCloseButton.CanFocused := False;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.Kind := scgpbgkClose;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.Thickness := 1;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.DisabledColor := clWhite;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.FocusedColor := cl_CLOSE_BUTTON;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.HotColor := cl_CLOSE_BUTTON;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColor := clWhite;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColor := cl_CLOSE_BUTTON_PRESSED;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.DisabledColorAlpha := 30;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.FocusedColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.HotColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.Visible := True;
end;

end.


Edit Actually discovered what was causing the problem: File Structure.
My file structure while facing the problem is:
Project Folder/
  ...
  ImprovedFluentPanel.pas
  TestForm.dproj
  ...
  Package/
    ...
    mycomponent.dproj
    ImprovedFluentPanel.pas

The project compiles because the file exists in the project folder (weirdly, given it's not added to the project in the IDE) AND the real file is in library path already, so the parser won't throw any error for accessing properties or something.
The compiler and the linker (both I couldn't find reference to understand why it happens) accept it gracefully, but compiles with the wrong unit, I checked it adding the following code to the ending of the wrong unit:
initialization

ShowMessage('The wrong init got compiled');

So, just renaming one of the files or deleting the one that shouldn't even exist fixed it.

So, I decided to follow the most basic advice ever: Started from scratch, did what I think was the exact same thing as I had in the previous project and now it works just fine. Anyways here is the full code now:
Declaration
type
  TFluentTopBar = class(TscPanel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCloseButton, FMinimizeButton: TscGPGlyphButton;
    FIsMinimizeEnabled: Boolean;
    FOwnerForm: TComponent;

    function isMinimizeEnabled: Boolean;
    procedure SetMinimizeEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure CloseApplication(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MinimizeApplication(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetupComponent;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;

  published
    { Published declarations }
    property CloseButtonHeight: TscGPGlyphButton read FCloseButton;
    property MinimizeButton: TscGPGlyphButton read FMinimizeButton;
    property MinimizeEnabled: Boolean read isMinimizeEnabled write SetMinimizeEnabled;
  end;

procedure Register;

Definition
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Fluent Compositions', [TFluentTopBar]);
end;

{ TFluentTopBar }

procedure TFluentTopBar.CloseApplication(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FOwnerForm <> nil then
  begin
    if Application.MainForm.Equals(FOwnerForm) then
      Application.Terminate
    else
      (FOwnerForm as TForm).Close;
  end;

end;

constructor TFluentTopBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  //T
  inherited;
  FMinimizeButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FMinimizeButton.SetSubComponent(true);
  FMinimizeButton.SetParentComponent(Self);
  FMinimizeButton.Align := alRight;
  FMinimizeButton.CanFocused := False;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FocusedColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.DisabledColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.HotColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FrameDisabledColor := clNone;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FrameFocusedColor := clNone;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FramePressedColor := clNone;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FrameNormalColor := clNone;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FrameHotColor := clNone;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.FrameWidth := 0;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.HotColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.NormalColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.NormalColor2 := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.PressedColor := clMinimizeButtonPressed;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.HotColorAlpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.NormalColorAlpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.NormalColor2Alpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.Options.PressedColorAlpha := 255;

  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.FocusedColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.DisabledColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.HotColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.HotColor := clMinimizeButton;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColor := clWhite;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColor := clMinimizeButtonPressed;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.HotColorAlpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColorAlpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColorAlpha := 255;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.Kind := scgpbgkMinus;
  FMinimizeButton.GlyphOptions.Thickness := 1;

  FCloseButton := TscGPGlyphButton.Create(Self);
  FCloseButton.SetSubComponent(true);
  FCloseButton.SetParentComponent(Self);
  FCloseButton.Align := alRight;
  FCloseButton.CanFocused := False;
  FCloseButton.Options.FocusedColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.DisabledColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.HotColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.FrameDisabledColor := clNone;
  FCloseButton.Options.FrameFocusedColor := clNone;
  FCloseButton.Options.FramePressedColor := clNone;
  FCloseButton.Options.FrameNormalColor := clNone;
  FCloseButton.Options.FrameHotColor := clNone;
  FCloseButton.Options.FrameWidth := 0;
  FCloseButton.Options.HotColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.NormalColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.NormalColor2 := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.Options.PressedColor := clCloseButtonPressed;
  FCloseButton.Options.HotColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.Options.NormalColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.Options.NormalColor2Alpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.Options.PressedColorAlpha := 255;

  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.FocusedColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.DisabledColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.HotColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.HotColor := clCloseButton;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColor := clWhite;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColor := clCloseButtonPressed;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.HotColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.NormalColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.PressedColorAlpha := 255;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.Kind := scgpbgkClose;
  FCloseButton.GlyphOptions.Thickness := 1;

  FCloseButton.OnClick := CloseApplication;
  FMinimizeButton.OnClick := MinimizeApplication;

  Self.Align:= alTop;
  Self.Height := 28;
  Self.DragForm := True;
  FIsMinimizeEnabled := FMinimizeButton.Visible and FMinimizeButton.Enabled;

  FOwnerForm := Nil;
  SetupComponent;
end;

function TFluentTopBar.isMinimizeEnabled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FIsMinimizeEnabled;
end;

procedure TFluentTopBar.MinimizeApplication(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FOwnerForm <> nil then
  begin
    if Application.MainForm.Equals(FOwnerForm) then
      Application.Minimize
    else
      (FOwnerForm as TForm).WindowState := wsMinimized;
  end;
end;

procedure TFluentTopBar.SetMinimizeEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FMinimizeButton.Visible := Value;
  FMinimizeButton.Enabled := Value;
  FCloseButton.Left := Self.Width;
  FIsMinimizeEnabled := Value;
end;

procedure TFluentTopBar.SetupComponent;
begin
  if not TryGetOwnerForm(Self, FOwnerForm) then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('It was not possible to find the owner TForm.');
  end;
  
  if not (FOwnerForm is TForm) then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('FOwnerForm is not a TForm.');
  end;
end;


So what changed? Highlighting the specifics will help future readers with similar problems.

Nothing relevant changed in the code. The problem was in the file structure. I moved the package away from the form (as they are inside the same proj group but are different projects and it started wrong). I did it in the very early, before writing any line of code. I'll indeed clarify what happened on the answer post.
